# How to implement a process overseeing another process?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Currently at my workplace I have a script named "batch launcher" (written in `bash`), which is supposed to oversee the execution of batches, logging their output and processing the return code of the batch. This is currently done via `env` call within this "batch launcher":

```
env $BATCH_ENV $BATCH_NAME $BATCH_OPTIONS >> $OUT_FILE 2>&1
```

Several days ago, one of the batches written in `perl` made a kill call on PGID (to eliminate all forked children), and since "batch launcher" shares PGID with anything it spawns, it got killed as well by this call.

How should I properly ensure that any PGID kill call will leave "batch launcher" intact, and report back that the process it was overseeing was killed?

I have so far heard of `setsid -w` command to solve this issue, but I was unable to get it working in combination with `env` call.

Comment: What exactly did your attempts at a `setsid` based solution look like? Did they fail with some sort of error, or they just failed to prevent the supervisor process from getting killed?

Comment: `setsid -w env ...` results in the following message in the output log: `execvp: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the stupid mistake of consulting online documentation rather than calling `man` in the system where I currently work. This [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html) states that `setsid` supports flags, dated July 2014. My man page is dated November 1993 (I work on RHEL 5), and has no flag support whatsoever.

What happened was `setsid` was trying to parse the `-w` flag as a file name, resulting in *execvp: No such file or directory* error. Once I removed the flag, everything works. The end command now looks like:

```
env $BATCH_ENV setsid $BATCH_NAME $BATCH_OPTIONS >> $OUT_FILE 2>&1
```

Anything that now gets launched from "batch launcher" is assigned SID and PGID equal to PID of `$BATCH_NAME`, and kill calls on PGID of `$BATCH_NAME` leaves the "batch launcher" unaffected, which now happily reports return status 143 (`SIGTERM`).